# Invalid dynamic route name using React-router 2.4.0

Tags: react-router

I'm using react-router version `2.4.0` and i'm unable to solve if path like this

`sari.yanti`

actually this is the username where user will get it own pages along with their username. But how do I get react-router to work with path like that

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by adding this to my webpack dev server config:

```
 historyApiFallback: {
disableDotRule: true
```

}

or by this

```
devServer: {
   proxy: {
'/*.*': { // Match all URL's with period/dot
  target: 'http://localhost:8080/',  // send to webpack dev server
  rewrite: function(req){
    req.url='index.html';  // Send to react app
  }
}
```

}
}

Comment: is that equivalent to production?